# SwiftUI: get currently focused NavigationView item index on tvOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos, navigationview

I am building a tvOS app with SwiftUI. Here is how it looks:

[image]

I want green label at the top to display the number of currently focused element.

Here is the code:

```
Text(selection ?? "no value").background(Color.green)
```

and

```
NavigationView {
  ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack{

       VStack {
          NavigationLink(destination: view2, tag: "1", selection: $selection) {
              Image("placeholder").scaledToFit().frame(width:300, height: 170) }
              Text("Button").foregroundColor(Color(.white)).padding(.top,10)
       } 
       
       VStack {
          NavigationLink(destination: view2, tag: "1", selection: $selection) {
              Image("placeholder").scaledToFit().frame(width:300, height: 170) }
              Text("Button").foregroundColor(Color(.white)).padding(.top,10)
       } 

       ...
      
       }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomLeading)
    }
 }
```

How should I implement this?